# Changing default audio device in Pulseaudio

Tags: linux, hdmi, alsa, pulse-audio

I would like to use HDMI on my graphic card for audio output. ALSA shows it as a card with 4 devices and I can get sound through one of them (the other three are different channels, perhaps? I have only stereo output connected). Although Pulseaudio has the right card set as default, it seems to me that it plays on a wrong device. *Pacmd* shows that the sink has parameter *alsa.device* set to the first device listed by ALSA, but I can get sound only from the second one.

How can I force Pulseaudio to use another device of the same card as a default output?

Or how can I force ALSA to switch numbers of the first and the second device on the card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like I found a solution, at least for this particular case.
Since I knew the card and device number assigned by ALSA, I just had to open */etc/pulse/default.pa*. in editor and change this line

```
#load-module module-alsa-sink
```

into this

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:2,7
```

where 2 and 7 are my particular instances of card and device numbers.
This created a new sink connected to the correct device, which was then used as the default output.

Answer (score 1):

*PulseAudio Device Chooser* (*padevchooser*)?

Comment: Unfortunately, _padevchooser_ needs name of the sink to connect to, but the device I want to use is not available among Pulseaudio sinks. I would have to create it first, or modify the one with different _alsa.device_ parameter. Both things lie beyond the bounds of my current knowledge and abilities.